# ¿Es correcta la expresión "cómo de bueno es"?

Tags: gramática, adverbios, preguntas

¿Es correcto decir lo siguiente?

> ¿**Cómo de bueno es** este método?

¿Es acaso mejor decir ***qué tan bueno es***?

Comment: ¿Qué investigación has hecho al respecto, Cris? Parece que ambas son correctas, pero sería interesante explicar tus hipótesis, así como dónde usar o quieres usar esta pregunta. Dale una ojeada al [tour] y a [ask] para luego darle a [edit] y así mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Ser de bueno no es idiomatico.

Answer (score 4):

"¿Cómo de + adjetivo?" no me suena idiomático. No obstante, la estructura resulta correcta si se inserta al menos una cópula u otro verbo entre el adverbio interrogativo y la frase preposicional (que define la magnitud o el aspecto respecto del cual se pregunta el grado o la cantidad):

- ¿Cómo **es** de bueno este método?
- ¿Cómo **te resultó** de bueno este método? / ¿Cómo **te resultó este método** de bueno?

La otra estructura permite sin inconvenientes la adyacencia de ambos elementos:

- ¿**Qué tan bueno** es este método?

Por último, encontramos la más formal -- y menos usual -- "¿Cuán + adjectivo?" (donde *cuán* fusiona el interrogativo *qué* y el adverbio *tan*):

- ¿**Cuán bueno** es este método?

Comment: ¡Buena! De hecho el DRAE ya menciona en [_cómo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9xX6XpW): _3. adv. interrog. Pregunta sobre la cantidad o el grado cuando modifica a adjetivos o adverbios precedidos de la preposición de. Me pregunto cómo de interesante resultaría la reunión. ¿Cómo quieres el bocadillo de grande?_.

Comment: El *cómo de* a mí suena mejor que *qué tan*, creo que es meramente una diferencia geográfica/dialectal.  *cuán*, por cierto, viene de un apócope de *cuánto* y no viene de *qué tan* (no sé querías decirlo, pero así lo leí a primeras).

Comment: @guifa Lo que quise decir es que "cuán" reúne los dos conceptos, la interrogación de "qué" y la cuantificación/intensificación de "tan".

Comment: Llego un poco tarde, pero: "¿Cómo de + adjectivo?" es la forma más normal de decirlo en España (sin necesidad de introducir nada entre el "como" y el "de"). La forma "¿Qué tan + adjetivo?" parece ser la preferida en Latinoamérica.

Comment: Abundando en lo que dice @wimi, que es correcto, me parece interesante señalar que la forma *qué tan* es la más antigua, aunque ha caído en desuso en España.

Answer (score 2):

La tercera acepción de la palabra [cómo](https://dle.rae.es/c%C3%B3mo) en el DLE es

> 3. adv. interrog. Pregunta sobre la cantidad o el grado cuando modifica a adjetivos o adverbios precedidos de la preposición de. *Me pregunto cómo de interesante resultaría la reunión. ¿Cómo quieres el bocadillo de grande?*

La entrada [tanto](https://dle.rae.es/tanto) en el DLE también incluye

> **qué tan, o qué tanto**
>
> 1. locs. advs. desus. Cuán, cuánto o cómo de. U. en oraciones interrogativas o exclamativas. U. en Am. *Depende de qué tan trabajadores sean ustedes.*

Por lo tanto, **las dos formas de decirlo son correctas**:

- ¿Cómo de bueno es este método?
- ¿Qué tan bueno es este método?

La forma "¿Cómo de ...?" es predominante en España, según mi experiencia. La forma "¿Qué tan ...?" predomina en Latinoamérica, como dice el DLE.

Answer (score 1):

Quédate con

> ¿Qué tan bueno es este método?

o mejor:

> ¿Qué tal este método?

y

> ¿Qué te parece este método?

Comment: De todos modos, sería útil explicar si es correcto decir _cómo de bueno es_.

Comment: @fedorqui - La verdad, no sé.  (¿Tú qué piensas?)  Se oye muy extraña la pregunta así como se planteó, y aunque fuera correcta no me parece buena idea que un principiante se acostumbrara a expresarse así.

Comment: A mí la verdad es que me suena bastante bien. Quizá por influencia del catalán, donde es una construcción muy común. Por [lo que dice guifa](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20753/es-correcta-la-expresi%C3%B3n-c%C3%B3mo-de-bueno-es/20766?noredirect=1#comment31788_20756), será algo que dependa de la zona de cada cual...

Comment: Mi primer comentario, por cierto, iba en el sentido que la respuesta ahora mismo no está dando explicación, sino sugerencia. Mira a ver si puedes mejorarla incluyendo alguna referencia para que resulte más útil para quien preguntó.